# Windows 10 Home asks for activation on 1803

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8, windows-activation

My apologies if this has already been posted but I am unable to find information on this problem. I have a client running copy of Windows 10 (running the 1803 update) which he upgraded from Windows 8. The problem is that it keeps asking to be activated even though it is activated. 
I have extracted the product key, which I entered into the change product key section, which seemed to work until he updated his system from 1709 to 1803. The system keeps asking for the activation key so I put in the product key like before. The problem is that, whereas last time it just worked, it fails to activate because it can't find the organisational activation server which he doesn't have.
My question is whether a complete reinstall is my only option or, since he is not keen on reinstalling the whole system (he uses it for his ERP system), whether there is another option?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something got messed-up by the 1803 update, which apparently was already
shaky after the 1709 update.

Do a
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html)
using a 1803 ISO file, to put all components of Windows on the same edition.
This will keep all applications and their settings.
Some few settings of Windows may still need to be redone.

Take first a backup of the client's disk.